# Viewing Port Info FC Solaris 11

Tags: solaris, san, fc

I have a hba card with two ports (port 0) and (port 1) and I want to know how can obtaining using OS the info to mapping the wwn that I can see using fcinfo hba-port command to a port of the hba card.

For example:
If I have a WWN ending on xxxx890B, see that wwn is on port 0 of the hba card.

Comment: Does `scanpci -v` show the WWN? (`scanpci` is probably in `/usr/X11/bin`)  I don't have access to a Solaris instance with any HBAs right now to know for sure.

Comment: This command does not show the required information. :( .
Output is here:

pci domain 0x0003 bus 0x0002 cardnum 0x00 function 0x00: vendor 0x1077 device 0x2532
 QLogic Corp. ISP2532-based 8Gb Fibre Channel to PCI Express HBA
 CardVendor 0x1077 card 0x0171 (QLogic Corp., Card unknown)
  STATUS    0x0010  COMMAND 0x0147
  CLASS     0x0c 0x04 0x00  REVISION 0x02
  BIST      0x00  HEADER 0x80  LATENCY 0x00  CACHE 0x10
  BASE0     0x00000300 SIZE 256  I/O
  BASE1     0x00100000 SIZE 16384  MEM
  BASEROM   0x00140000 SIZE 262144
  MAX_LAT   0x00  MIN_GNT 0x00  INT_PIN 0x01  INT_LINE 0x00

Answer (score 0):

`fcinfo hba-port` is the command you're looking for, and `Port WWN` is the field that indicates the WWN specific to a port (vs the `Node WWN`, which is specific to the card).

More information is available at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54792/gqgjd.html.  And while the docs are specific to Solaris 11.3, `fcinfo` should work on any version from Solaris 10 to current.

Comment: This command does not provide me the required information. I mean, How can I map /dev/cfg/cX to a physical port on the hba card?.

Comment: You should see the port WWNs, like `HBA Port WWN: 2100001b329ca67b` and `HBA Port WWN: 2101001b32bca67b`.  If you look at the first 4 characters of the WWN, you'll see `2100` and `2101`.  In my experience with Solaris, characters 3-4 are always used for port identification.   So in my example, 2100 is port 0, and 2101 is port 1 on a dual-port HBA.

Comment: I used the fcinfo hba-port command again and I did not see that info:

I have two physical hba cards with two ports each one.

HBA Port WWN: 10000090fa1c0e42
        Node WWN: 20000090fa1c0e42
HBA Port WWN: 10000090fa1c0e43
        Node WWN: 20000090fa1c0e43
HBA Port WWN: 10000090fa1c044c
        Node WWN: 20000090fa1c044c
HBA Port WWN: 10000090fa1c044d
        Node WWN: 20000090fa1c044d

I cannot see in which PCI slot they are and in which physical port are each WWN.

Regards,

Comment: I forgot about the PCI slot info.  There should be an "OS Device Path" field in the `fcinfo` output.  You may be able to dig into that OS Device path and figure out the PCI Slot.

Comment: I have /dev/cfg/c3 and /dev/cfg/c4. I cannot find the relation about which WWN is on what port in my hba card. :S.

Comment: What do the command `cfgadm -al c3` and `cfgadm -al c4` show you?

Comment: Here is the output:

Ap_Id                          Type         Receptacle   Occupant     Condition
c4                             fc-fabric    connected    configured   unknown
c4::50060e80103ae050           disk         connected    configured   unknown

Ap_Id                          Type         Receptacle   Occupant     Condition
c3                             fc-fabric    connected    configured   unknown
c3::202700a0b86e5e1c           disk         connected    configured   unknown
c3::50060e80103ae058           disk         connected    configured   unusable

Comment: Thanks.  Can you tell me what `prtdiag -v` shows you?

Comment: Here is the output:

00  PCIe  1       1, abcd, 108e       2,  0,  2  okay     8,    8  network-pciex108e,abcd         SUNW,pcie-qgc
    /pci@1,700000/network@0,2

00  PCIe  1       1, abcd, 108e       2,  0,  3  okay     8,    8  network-pciex108e,abcd         SUNW,pcie-qgc
    /pci@1,700000/network@0,3

00  PCIe  3       2, 2532, 1077       2,  0,  0  okay     8,    8  SUNW,qlc-pciex1077,2532        QLE2562
    /pci@3,700000/SUNW,qlc@0

00  PCIe  3       2, 2532, 1077       2,  0,  1  okay     8,    8  SUNW,qlc-pciex1077,2532        QLE2562